# "On the causes and consequences of deviations from rational behaviour"

Tags: applied-econometrics

The title of this post is the title of a paper I am drawing inspiration from for my final year dissertation. If anyone has the time, https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3623676, this is the link to the paper and I would like to ask if anyone could give me pointers as to what I would need to learn to carry out similar research? Specifically my technical econometric skills are very rusty so I don't know what I would need to brush up on to carry out similar analysis to section 3 of the paper.